# c++ gsoap, custom fault handling for stand alone services in namespaces

Tags: c++, gsoap

I have created multiple stand alone services using  C++ namespace via gsoap, how do I customize soap faults? One possible way is by adding soap fault structures in env.h, but it would be combined for all services, I want faults processing separate for every service. Is there any other way ?

Comment: There is a `struct SOAP_ENV__Fault *fault;` in the soap structure so you should be able to make a structure derived from SOAP_ENV__Fault and assign it to soap->fault.  I do that kind of thing for custom headers.

Comment: You are suggesting right, but the problem is I have my services compiled as c++ namespace and multiple fault & header handling one in envC.cpp that is accessible to stdsoap2.cpp & other in service specific <namespace><servicename>C.cpp file, which is creating ambiguity. I need to service specific exception structure in case of fault, which is not happening instead the general handling of fault is done.

Comment: gsoap documentation suggest a way http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.35 but it doesn't seem practical to me, whenever I add a new service in my code, i would need to update env.h to add its service specific fault......